# How to remove "Apps Available for Download" from the applications lens?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

Is there some way to modify the Applications lens in Unity so that we can remove the **"Apps Available for Download"** section?

The section is really annoying for normal use. We don't have to know why we can download some random games every time we want to start an application.

Also, it may make the lens even faster as it will only have to display installed applications rather than creating some random list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm afraid this is not possible in 11.04 or 11.10, but [it is possible](https://askubuntu.com/a/100396/235) in 12.04.

Answer (score 15):

This is possible in Unity version 5.0, which will be part of Ubuntu 12.04.

To get rid of the "**Apps Available for Download**" section:

1. launch `dconf-editor` (which is part of the [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools] package)
2. navigate to `/desktop/unity/lenses/applications`
3. uncheck the `display-available-apps` box

[image]

(There's also a `display-recent-apps` option available to disable the corresponding section.)

And yeah, I'm the author of that patch :-)

Related:

- [How to remove "frequently used programs" from menu dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100424/how-to-remove-frequently-used-programs-from-menu-dash)

Comment: Thank you very much! Unity should just remember the setting you choose on the options menu.

Answer (score 2):

## 12.10

MyUnity unfortunately up to now is not able to do this due to the new version of Unity in 12.10 (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/203709/54949) related question).

You can use **[Unsettings](http://florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/index.html)** to do this. [Here](http://florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/index.html#download) you can find the .deb package and if you want you can also add the ppa.

To disable the "Apps available for download", go to the Dash menu and switch off Apps for download.

## [12.04](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/myunity)

(click to install)

Configuration of *Display Available Apps to download* is directly configurable from the Dash

[image]

1. Open the Dash
2. Click the lens as Application Lens
3. Click the down arrow to reveal the *Filter Results* options

[image]

- To switch off the display of applications to download click the *Local Apps* source
- To turn on the display of applications to download click the *Software Centre* or *All*

---

Configuration of *Display Available Apps* and its counterpart *Display Recent Apps* is now available directly via the GUI configuration application *MyUnity*

[image]

The image shows the option turned off - you can *click* as shown to switch-on the Dash display of available applications.

---

Related:

- [How to remove "frequently used programs" from menu dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100424/how-to-remove-frequently-used-programs-from-menu-dash)

Answer (score 0):

I've released [RunLens](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/runlens/), which is some kind of an application lens without the "Apps Available for Download" section. It's still under development but may already be useful for some people.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible also in 12.10 with [**Unsettings**](http://florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/index.html) by Florian Diesch. It can disable downloadable apps on the application lens.

One has to go to the dash setting panel in the Unsettings application and turn off the switch "Apps for download".

It can also do lots of other nice things for customizing Unity.