# How do I remove "apps available for download" from 11.04

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove “Apps Available for Download” from the applications lens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37747/how-to-remove-apps-available-for-download-from-the-applications-lens)

There may be other similiar questions. But I find this advertising as really unnecessary.
It becomes useless and annoying after a while.

The whole 11.04 package looks pretty professional, Until the apps available for download pops up. There is already a software center. I hope they make a way to remove it. I don't know where to leave feedback for Ubuntu 11.04. Still working out a few problems on amd64 installation. But overall I am happy with 11.04 and unity.

Comment: It's unprofessional indeed. I distinctly remember that the first thing presented to me after clicking the Applications icon in a fresh installation was something called *Porn Viewer*.

Answer (score 0):

This is Canonical design, and they have idea how it should be used. You probably won't be able to remove this feature. Except if someone makes hack.