# How do I increase the icon size in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, accessibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I increase the font size in Dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97503/how-do-i-increase-the-font-size-in-dash)

As my partner is registered blind she has difficulty with small text & icons. In 11.04 using Unity the Icons look quite good but I was checking the Assistive Technology section to see what was available only to find that it was Gnome based.

So far I prefer the Unity looks and would like to know what options I have to increase icon sizes if that is what she prefers.

Another thing that could possibly assist would be to remove clutter.  Is it possible to remove the Apps available for download section as this would offer more scope for increasing the visual effects?

Answer (score 2):

**Changing the icon size**

1. Install [compizconfig-settings-manager[image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `about:config` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Unity configuration.
3. In the *Experimental* tab, there is a slider to set the Launcher icon size:

   [image]

**Removing *Apps Available for Download***

- Unfortunately, [this isn't currently possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37747/how-to-remove-apps-available-for-download-from-the-applications-lens).

Comment: Since this question is a duplicate, it'd be best if you could please delete your answer so people in the future get redirected to the duplicate. Thanks!