# How to remove “Apps Available for Download” from Dash?

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove “Apps Available for Download” from the applications lens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37747/how-to-remove-apps-available-for-download-from-the-applications-lens)

I know that this isn't possible in Natty, but this could be done in 11.10?

Answer (score 1):

No, I haven't found a way to remove them in oneiric. It's one of the few things that really annoys me. It would be nice to display those if you search for an application that isn't installed, but we should not have advertisements in the dash -- at least not by default.