# How to remove "frequently used programs" from menu dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

How can I remove "frequently used programs" from the menu?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible with earlier versions of Unity but will be possible in Unity 5.0: see the image in one of the answers here:

To get rid of the "**Most frequently used programs**" section:

1. launch `dconf-editor` (which is part of the [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools] package)
2. navigate to `/desktop/unity/lenses/applications`
3. uncheck the `display-recent-apps` box

[image]

Related:

- [How to remove "Apps Available for Download" from the applications lens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37747/how-to-remove-apps-available-for-download-from-the-applications-lens)

Answer (score 2):

## [12.04](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/myunity)

(click to install)

Configuration of *Display Recent Apps* and its counterpart *Display Available Apps* is now available directly via the GUI application *MyUnity*

[image]

The image shows the option turned off - you can *click* as shown to switch-on the Dash display of recent apps.

---

Related:

- [How to remove "Apps Available for Download" from the applications lens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37747/how-to-remove-apps-available-for-download-from-the-applications-lens/108296#108296)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install unity 5.0 on 11.10:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/staging
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I have upgraded, works perfectly.