# Can I change from Recent apps to Most frequent apps

Tags: unity, 12.10, unity-dash, lenses, applications-lens

I'd like to change the way Unity selects apps for the application lens from "Most recent" to "Most frequent" but I can find no way to do this. What to do? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do so without changing the source code. Ubuntu, till now, does not provide any option to change this behaviour.

However, this link can be of some help: [How to remove “frequently used programs” from menu dash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/100424/83046)