# Disable recommendation on application lens

Tags: unity, 13.04, lenses

For some reason, my choice of disabling display for uninstalled applications is not a reminder during sessions. Even though I choose it all the time.

It makes the application lens dead slow on first runs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean removing the so-called 'ads' in there?

Go to 'System Settings'

Then Privacy

Uncheck Include Online Search Results.

Done.

Comment: No, I don't mean that. 
In fact. This answers my question http://askubuntu.com/q/37747/17.